# How to segment data of a report using AdWords Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I need to create a report that shows me the Cost for ads by I need to divide this data by Placement (DisplayName) and AdType and Device and AdvertisingChannelType. I´ve searched extensively the documentation and I found out that there is no single report that can cross all this dimensions. In the UI I can just create a segment, how ever I can figure out how to do it using the script. I´ve tried doing this:

```
var placementReport = AdWordsApp.report(
     'SELECT AdGroupName, AdvertisingChannelType, AdGroupId , AdType, device, DisplayName, Cost ' +
     'FROM   PLACEMENT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
     'WHERE DisplayName CONTAINS "mail.google.com" ' +
     'DURING 20151022,20151022');
```

But it just doesn´t work.

How do I break my report in segments?

I need to get a very specific data. I´m searching for a way to segment the Cost of a Ad by Device, placement and adtype, for example:

```
AdId: 320930902 > Device: Mobile > Placement: Youtube > adtype: Ad Text > Cost: $35.00
AdId: 320930902 > Device: Mobile > Placement: Youtube > adtype: Ad Image > Cost: $5.00
AdId: 320930902 > Device: Computer > Placement: Youtube > adtype: Ad Image > Cost: $45.00
AdId: 320930902 > Device: Computer > Placement: Youtube > adtype: Ad Text> Cost: $50.00
```

And so on... Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "...Cost for ads by..." something; but what? Please clarify.